# How to set class_weight in keras package of R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am using `keras` package in R to train a deep learning model. My data set is highly imbalanced. Therefore, I want to set `class_weight` argument in the `fit` function. Here is the fit function and its arguments that I used for my model

```
history <- model %>% fit(
  trainData, trainClass, 
  epochs = 5, batch_size = 1000, 
  class_weight = ????,
  validation_split = 0.2
)
```

In python I can set `class_weight` as follow:

```
class_weight={0:1, 1:30}
```

But I am not sure how to do it in R. In the help menu of R it describes `class_weight` as follow:

> Optional named list mapping indices (integers) to a weight (float) to
>   apply to the model's loss for the samples from this class during
>   training. This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention"
>   to samples from an under-represented class.

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: I have no experience with keras but first thing I would try is `list("0" = 1, "1" = 30)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Class_weight needs to be a list, so

```
    history <- model %>% fit(
        trainData, trainClass, 
        epochs = 5, batch_size = 1000, 
        class_weight = list("0"=1,"1"=30),
        validation_split = 0.2
    )
```

seems to work. Keras internally uses a function called as_class_weights to change the list to a python-dictionary (see https://rdrr.io/cran/keras/src/R/model.R).

```
     class_weight <- dict(list('0'=1,'1'=10))
     class_weight
     >>> {0: 1.0, 1: 10.0}
```

Looks just like the python dictionary that you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I [found a generic solution](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1875#issuecomment-273752868) in Python solution, so I converted into R:

```
counter=funModeling::freq(Y_data_aux_tr, plot=F) %>% select(var, frequency)
majority=max(counter$frequency)
counter$weight=ceil(majority/counter$frequency)


l_weights=setNames(as.list(counter$weight), counter$var)
```

Using it:

```
 fit(..., class_weight = l_weights)
```

*An advice if you are using `fit_generator`: since the weights are based on frequency, having a different number of training-validation samples may bias the validation results. They should be equally-sized.*