# class_weight parameter in keras::fit() error. Classes exist in data but not in class_weight

Tags: r, class, keras, deep-learning

I have a slightly imbalanced data set to which I'm attempting to assign weights to.

The example provided in [How to set class_weight in keras package of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907881/how-to-set-class-weight-in-keras-package-of-r?answertab=active#tab-top) does not work for me. When I try the same, with my code:

```
system.time ( 
  baseline_history <- fit (
    object           = model_baseline,            
    x                = as.matrix(x_train_tbl), 
    y                = y_train_vec,             
    batch_size       = 1024,    
    epochs           = 30,    
    class_weight = list("0" = 1, "1" = 1.67),
    validation_split = 0.2) )
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: `class_weight` must contain all classes in the data. The classes {'0', '1'} exist in the data but not in `class_weight`.
```

I'm at a bit of a loss, since I explicitly state in class_weights that it is a list. I even tried

```
weights <- list("0" = 1, "1" = 1.67)
> weights
$`0`
[1] 1

$`1`
[1] 1.67

is.list(weights)
[1] TRUE
```

To make sure it worked, but I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have your `y_train_vec` as a factor, that's the problem right there.

For some reason, `class_weight` seems to not work well with factors so you can simply change it to numeric

`y_train_vec = as.numeric(y_train_vec)`

This should give you the internal representation of your factors (it should give you a list of 1's and 2's), and then you can specify the `class_weight` accordingly

```r
system.time(
    baseline_history <- fit (
        object           = model_baseline,            
        x                = as.matrix(x_train_tbl), 
        y                = as.matrix(y_train_vec),             
        batch_size       = 1024,    
        epochs           = 30,    
        class_weight = list("1" = 1, "2" = 1.67),
        validation_split = 0.2)
    )
)
```

Note now that the classes in `class_weight` are "1" and "2"

Hope this helped.